# My Textbox seemingly randomly duplicates

Tags: c#, combobox, system.io.file

When the form first loads, a folder is created

```
System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory("Z:/Daniel/AccountInfo");
```

Whenever an account is created in the program, a file is created in this location

`FileStream createAccountFile = new FileStream("Z:/Daniel/AccountInfo/" + lastNameBox.Text + "_" + firstNameBox.Text + ".txt", FileMode.CreateNew);`

Whenever a button on the program is clicked, text is appended to `accountInfoText` and all the text inside of there is now appended to the same location that was created above.

```
string addInfo = DateTime.Now.ToString("M/d/yyyy") + " - Email - Too Soon" + Environment.NewLine;
accountInfoText.AppendText(addInfo);
File.AppendAllText("Z:/Daniel/AccountInfo/" + lastNameInfoBox.Text + "_" + firstNameInfoBox.Text + ".txt", accountInfoText.Text);
```

Whenever the combobox `accountComboBox` has it's index changed, all text that inside of the file that previously written to, is now inside of `accountInfoText`

```
string accountInfo = System.IO.File.ReadAllText("Z:/Daniel/AccountInfo/" + lastNameInfoBox.Text + "_" + firstNameInfoBox.Text + ".txt");
accountInfoText.Text = accountInfo;
```

The issue is, after I press the button that does the appending, when I go ahead and select a different account from `accountComboBox` the text inside of `accountInfoText` and inside of the actual text file gets doubled. I haven't been able to see what triggers it.

Thanks for all the help!

Comment: Simple question to start with - Have you cleared the variables from the previous values before working with a new account?

Comment: All my variables are local. And yes =]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You append twice:

```
accountInfoText.AppendText(addInfo);
File.AppendAllText("Z:/Daniel/AccountInfo/" + lastNameInfoBox.Text + "_" + firstNameInfoBox.Text + ".txt", accountInfoText.Text);
```

first you append your `addInfo` to the `accountInfoText`, then you add `accountInfoText` to your file. Since the file already contais the old `addInfo`, and so does your `accountInfoText`. So it is doubled.

Edit: You might just want to add the `addInfo` to the file:

```
File.AppendAllText("Z:/Daniel/AccountInfo/" + lastNameInfoBox.Text + "_" + firstNameInfoBox.Text + ".txt", addInfo);
```

Comment: You were 100% correct. Thank you! And sorry for the stupid question lol